# Clear TextView from text and background

Tags: android

I have a TextView called choice1 that I use for both text and image.
I know that this:

```
choice1.setText("");
```

clears it from text and this

```
choice1.setBackgroundResource(0);
```

clears it from any image.

Is there a way to clear it completely in 1 command or do I always have to run both commands to clear the TextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reaaaaally wanted to I guess you could make your own method..

```
private void clearTextView(TextView tv) {
    tv.setText(""); 
    tv.setBackgroundResource(0);
}
```

And then

```
clearTextView(choice1);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no single command to do both together, you have to call it separately.